# how/where to set --profile.api option for jruby running inside jruby-rack/tomcat?

Tags: jruby, jruby-rack

how/where to set `--profile.api` option for jruby running inside jruby-rack/tomcat?

This option is documented in how to profile a block of code [here](http://danlucraft.com/blog/2011/03/built-in-profiler-in-jruby-1.6/)

Answer (score 3):

using `JRUBY_OPTS` won't work due how JRuby profiling is implemented - it only supported profiling a single "main" runtime ... now I was actually trying to make it work with an arbitrary runtime and my code got merged into **1.7** https://github.com/jruby/jruby/pull/96 but it still might require testing and work to be done.

for the record there's also a context paramater for setting arguments (command-line style) when using JRuby-Rack, thus if you had a JRuby version that can profile any runtime you will need to add the following code :

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>jruby.runtime.arguments</param-name>
  <param-value>--profile.api</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

add to $JRUBY_OPTS

Example:

```
JRUBY_OPTS="--profile.api"
```